# How to convert a Python program (.py) to Application (.exe) which is a Tesseract-OCR dependent?

Tags: python, windows, exe

I tried to convert my python code file to an application using the `pyinstaller` package. It's all set!

When I try to open the app file in the dist folder, on a computer which doesn't have python installed, the app's functionality is not good. It's not working properly (according to what I actually coded it for).

I'm mentioning this because the `.exe` file was tend to run on any system irrespective of the system having the Python installed (the same runs perfectly on my system which has python installed).

The thing is, I also have Tesserat-OCR installed on my system which seems to be mandating its existence on the any system that runs the application. If so, how can I do it without having to require it in the system?

So, how could it be done so as to build it better?

Comment: does the operating system changes on different machine?

Comment: atleast tell what is going wrong on different machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python software foundation has recently done a post on this: https://packaging.python.org/overview/

What you are asking is how to package your python programme into an executable.

py2exe if you are only using Windows is quite popular.